# Special code for .htaccess and robots.txt files

Tags: .htaccess

My client was noticing that his site was extremely slow yesterday morning so he contacted his WiredTree host, who suggested that we add the following code in the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase / 
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SemrushBot" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^DotBot" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^AhrefsBot" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

`Options +FollowSymlinks` is already in the file and `RewriteBase /` is currently commented out and I'm not sure if I should uncomment it, not knowing what affect that would have. Then I would add the 3 set commands and the deny command below it. Is it OK to uncomment this line and add the extra commands?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The only part that is on-topic for us is the part about the .htaccess file, since Drupal comes with one, and changes to it could interfere on Drupal. Explaining how to use the robots.txt file is off-topic since `Disallow: /` has the same effect whenever you are using Drupal or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the most important bit they want you to put in .htaccess is this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SemrushBot" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^DotBot" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^AhrefsBot" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

They should probably go inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block in your .htaccess file, just after `RewriteBase /` (whether it's commented out or not).
This `RewriteBase /` line shouldn't cause any problems, if your drupal site is not in a subdirectory (e.g. your index.php file shouldn't be in a sub-folder of your webroot like http://domain.com/drupal/index.php)

The `Options +FollowSymLinks` shouldn't need to be included twice if it's already there.